# Simple notation question: What does $(kG)^\times$ mean? $k$ is a field and $G$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, group-rings

I guess $kG$ is the group algebra over a finite group, i.e. the set of linear combinations of $k$ and group elements. But I do not understand the "$^\times$".

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this is $(kG)^{\times}$, which denotes the unit group of the group ring (or algebra) $kG$.

Answer (score 1):

$(kG)^{\times}$ denotes the group of invertible elements of $kG$, which is also called unit group or group of units of group algebra $kG$. It is also denoted by $\mathcal{U}(kG)$.